# 301 to 302 URL redirection

Tags: url, seo

Magento has the facility of 301/302 re-directs. I'm working on a project for which 301 works fine for each country, say if I'm visiting from India, it re-directs me to [example.in](http://example.in) from [example.com](http://example.com) . It's configured at System->Configuration->Web->Url Options->Auto-redirect to Base URL. Though I see re-directs are also configured in .htaccess file. like

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.*)\.html
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} [A-Z] 
RewriteRule . ${lc:%{REQUEST_URI}} [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

I see few other 301 re-directs are mentioned in .htaccess file like

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  ^/ShowReviewDetails\.do$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/saree.html? [R=301,L] 
# simple redirect
Redirect 301 /Craft.do    http://www.example.com/craft.html
Redirect 301 /Welcome.do  http://www.example.com/
Redirect 301 /Craft.do  http://www.example.com/craft.html
```

Which 301 re-direct is in action? **I've to change all 301 re-directs to 302**. Do I need to change 301->302 in admin section only or I need to change all occurrences of 301 to 302 in .htaccess file also?

Also, I see, in *Catalog->URL Rewrite Management* , 301 re-directs are enabled for each store view. Do I need to change it here also or I need to make change only at System->Configuration->Web->Url Options->Auto-redirect to Base URL ?

Comment: what your question i not understand it

Comment: use  in .htaccess file Try changing the last line to this:
RewriteRule .* index.php [R=301,L] in

Comment: @Ashvin: I want to do 302 URL re-directs for the site instead of using 301(presently active).

Comment: hi frinds admin go to System > Configuration > Web  > URL Options > Auto-redirect to Base URL and than change the option for 301.http://www.collaboration133.com/updating-301-redirects-in-magento-admin-via-url-rewrite-management/2080/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `.htaccess` file will be parsed before Magento will lookup its rewrite rules.

So if you want to handle a domain-level redirection with a 302, just change your `.htaccess` file and that's it.